# Cómo hacer un toolbar con color dinámico Android

Tags: android

Necesito hacer un toolbar donde tengo una activity con 6 imágenes. Dependiendo de la imagen que se selecciona, el toolbar tendrá un color y un título distinto: si tengo 6 imágenes o 6 iconos, tendré un toolbar con 6 colores y 6 títulos distintos.

Comment: Pero en concreto cual es tu duda? tienes algo de código ya armado?

Comment: No solo tengo un layout con 6 imagenes... quiero que al darle encima a una imagen me lleve a una activity con un toolbar distinto... lo que tengo me lleva al mismo toolbar ya que la app tiene el tema en general. Lo que quiero saber es si eso se puede o si una app solo se puede tener un solo toolbar siempre con el mismo color

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el código que ya tienes, si no lo haces te pueden cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno suponiendo que ya tienes tu lógica de lo que pasa al seleccionar la imagen lo único que restaría es cambiar el color y el titulo del toolbar para lo cual puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
public void cambiarColorToolbar(int color, String titulo){
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(color)));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titulo);
}
```

para usarlo lo único que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
cambiarColorToolbar(R.color.colorPrimary, "Mi String");
```

y ya con esto cambias dinámicamente el color y el titulo del toolbar

Comment: Gracias exactamente eso es lo que necesitaba.. Muchas gracias...